# How to give Read, Write Permissions using IPs in SAMBA

Tags: samba, file-sharing

I want to give Read and Write access based on the IPs instead of the Users in SAMBA using smb.conf

This is the Text I copied from my smb.conf file.

```
[TEST]
        comment = test
        path = /mnt/vg-stg/storage/test
        read only = no
        writeable = yes
        oplocks = yes
        level2 oplocks = yes
        force security mode = 0
        dos filemode = yes
        dos filetime resolution = yes
        dos filetimes = yes
        fake directory create times = no
   browseable = yes
   csc policy = manual
   veto oplock files = /*.mdb/*.MDB/*.dbf/*.DBF/
   veto files = /*:Zone.Identifier:*/
   store dos attributes = yes
   map acl inherit = yes
        create mode = 0777
        directory mode = 2777
        printable = no
        guest ok = yes
        hosts allow = 10.20.20.213
        #hosts readonly allow =

[TEST]
        comment = test
        path = /mnt/vg-stg/storage/test
        read only = yes
        writeable = no
        oplocks = yes
        level2 oplocks = yes
        force security mode = 0
        dos filemode = yes
        dos filetime resolution = yes
        dos filetimes = yes
        fake directory create times = no
   browseable = yes
   csc policy = manual
   veto oplock files = /*.mdb/*.MDB/*.dbf/*.DBF/
   veto files = /*:Zone.Identifier:*/
   store dos attributes = yes
   map acl inherit = yes
        create mode = 0777
        directory mode = 2777
        printable = no
        guest ok = yes
        hosts allow = 10.20.20.147
        #hosts readonly allow =
```

But the Samba is not picking up the changes. Because when i try to access from explorer or Nautilus it is giving me error

```
Could not display "smb://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/Reports
The file is of an unknown type
```

Please give me advice what im doing wrong here

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the options `hosts readonly allow` and `hosts write list` exist. btw: my samba/testparm do not either.
theoretically this should do what you expect:

```
[mainBak]
comment = Main Backup Writeable
    path = /mnt/vg-stg/storage/Main_Backup
    read only = no
    writeable = yes
    oplocks = yes
    level2 oplocks = yes
    force security mode = 0
    dos filemode = no
    dos filetime resolution = no
    dos filetimes = no
    fake directory create times = no
browseable = yes
csc policy = manual
veto oplock files = /*.mdb/*.MDB/*.dbf/*.DBF/
veto files = /*:Zone.Identifier:*/
store dos attributes = yes
map acl inherit = yes
    create mode = 0777
    directory mode = 2777
    printable = no
    guest ok = yes
    hosts allow = 10.91.12.109 10.91.12.115 10.91.12.95 10.91.12.67 10.91.12.109 10.91.12.115 10.20.20.147

[mainBak]
comment = Main Backup Readonly
        path = /mnt/vg-stg/storage/Main_Backup
        read only = yes
        writeable = no
        oplocks = yes
        level2 oplocks = yes
    force security mode = 0
    dos filemode = no
    dos filetime resolution = no
    dos filetimes = no
    fake directory create times = no
browseable = yes
csc policy = manual
veto oplock files = /*.mdb/*.MDB/*.dbf/*.DBF/
veto files = /*:Zone.Identifier:*/
store dos attributes = yes
map acl inherit = yes
    create mode = 0777
    directory mode = 2777
    printable = no
    guest ok = yes
    hosts allow = 10.20.20.0/24 10.20.50.0/24 172.16.0.0/16 192.168.0.0/16 10.91.12.252 10.20.20.94 10.91.12.46 10.91.12.197 10.91.12.87 10.91.12.106 10.91.12.110 10.91.12.12 10.91.12.108 10.91.12.62 10.91.12.129 10.91.12.127 10.91.12.128 10.91.12.50 10.91.12.142
```

Idea is to have same Name for share two times, but with different write-/read-rights and host-allows. If this is the only share you have in your config, you could export some options/settings to `[global]` to reduce redundancy.

access-check you could do with: `testparm /path/to/smb.conf hostname hostIP`

Comment: Thanks for replying xx4h, I thought that it will work but this time I created a test folder TEST and assigned permissions READ ONLY = YES, WRITEABLE =NO (On First Machine) and READ ONLY = NO, WRITEABLE =YES (On Second Machine). On First M. it is not opening folder and on Second Machine it is asking for the password. I have updated the Question on the TEST SCENARIO.

Answer (score 0):

My answer had to be backwards

So I setup where I have my main Read-Only Conf first then the Writeable one.

Here is the conf:

```
[ShareName]

comment = RO
path = /path
available = yes
hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1. 10. EXCEPT 192.168.1.203
read only = yes
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = no


[ShareName]

comment = WR
path = /path
available = yes
hosts allow = 192.168.1.203
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```